Suppose we have two variables $x,y \in [1,n]$. How can we write $x \neq y$ in integer-linear constraint?
If $x,y \in [1,n]$, how to write $x \neq y$ in integer-linear constraint?
Possible Answer:
$x−y\geq 1−(1−t)\times n$ and $y−x \geq 1−t\times n$ where $t \in \{0,1\}$

Do you refer to integer linear programming, or linear programming?

It is not a linear constraint, say $-1 \neq 1$ and $1\neq -1$ but $-1+1 = 1-1$. $=$ and $\geq$ are linear.

With linear programming: you can't.
With integer linear programming, here is one solution: introduce zero-or-one variable $t$, and the inequalities
$$x \le y - 1 + (1-t)n, \qquad x \ge y+1 - tn.$$
Intuition: if $t$ is 1, then we must have $x<y$; if $t$ is 0, then we must have $x>y$.
I have assumed that $x,y$ are integer variables and $n$ is a known constant.
My thanks to @Subhankar Ghosal for an improvement to my initial answer, which I have incorporated here.

Can we have the following? $x - y \geq 1 - (1-t)n$ and $y - x \geq 1 - tn$

@SubhankarGhosal, oh good point, that is a better solution.  I have revised my answer accordingly.
